# Parse Facebook comments graph API

Tags: php, json, facebook, comments

i have been looking for a way to properly parse the JSON object or associative array of similar facebook feeds in PHP:

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://lovebryan.com/friends/layne/data/upimages/ClevelandForest.jpg

```
$request_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=" . $purl;
$requests = file_get_contents($request_url);
$fb_response = json_decode($requests);
```

How can I implement a foreach function in PHP to extract the id's of each data member?

Comment: Care to share what you found Trent? I'm having the same issue. :/
THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fb_response = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($fb_response as $key => $value)
{
     // your code....
}
```

Comment: thank you! could you please provide an example of how the function can cycle through each of the "data" array elements in the JSON text and retrieve the "id" within the "from" element?